# Firebase realtime database query renders database unavailable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When performing the following query on our users (over 25,000), the request times out and ends up rendering the realtime database inaccessible from both the front end and the Firebase UI itself. This lasts for about 5 minutes. I do have an index set up on the email property.

Any ideas?

```
const users = await admin
  .database()
  .ref("users")
  .orderByChild("email")
  .startAt("example@example.com")
  .endAt("example@example.com")
  .once("value")

const results = []
users.forEach((user) => {
  results.push({
    uid: user.key,
    ...user.val(),
  })
})
```

Comment: Did you declare an index on `email` in your security rules?

Comment: Yes:
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
         ".indexOn": ["email"]
      }
   }
}

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your question to include that information with the link right under it.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that should make that query so slow. But can you try using `.equalTo("example@example.com")` instead of `.startAt("example@example.com").endAt("example@example.com")` to see if that makes a difference? It shouldn't, but... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯